# Add watermark to file during upload

Tags: php, upload, watermark

I'm trying to make an upload function which adds a watermark to every file uploaded in memory and then saves the files to a specific folder. However, I can't get the watermark part of the code to work. I know for sure that the upload functions works without the watermark code added to it. I believe that the error must be where the watermark code "transfers" the temporary file to the code that moves the file to the hard drive. How can I fix this problem?

The code is as follows:

```
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){

            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
            $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            //$file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];    

            //if($file_size > 2097152){

                //$errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
            //}
            // echo '<img src="../images/watermark.gif">';

            $q = "INSERT INTO media (file_name, album_id, file_size) VALUES ('$file_name','$album_id', '$file_size')";

            $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

            $desired_dir = '../../customers/' . $customerFolder . '/';

            // load the watermark and the photo
            $watermark = imagecreatefromgif('../images/watermark.gif');
            $photo = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tmp);

            // center watermark on the photo
            $wx = imagesx($photo)/2 - imagesx($watermark)/2;
            $wy = imagesy($photo)/2 - imagesy($watermark)/2;

            imagecopy($photo, $watermark, $wx, $wy, 0, 0, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));

            if(empty($errors)==true){

                    move_uploaded_file($photo,"$desired_dir".$file_name);

                //mysql_query($q);  

            }else{
                print_r($errors);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Careful... you have potentially opened yourself up to SQL injection attacks.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar.  Also, if that `$customerFolder` is coming from the user, make sure that the final path is only under a directory where you want it.  Don't let the user specify a filename.  Keep it out of the docroot.  Otherwise, it's nothing to upload `something-evil.php` and run it remotely.

Comment: also, avoid using "../../"

Comment: Pekka: The watermark isn't added and the file isn't uploaded. Brad: $customerFolder is a random string generated by the code and the files are stored outside of the root as well.

Comment: MarZab: Why should I avoid using "../../". It's kind of neccesary in my code since the code will be executed on different sub domains which is located in different folders... Or do you know a more efficient/better way to do it?

Comment: Prefer use `imagecopymerge`

Comment: @MarZab: Just notifying you of a question addressed to you by OP ;)

Comment: thanks @Aquillo. its valid but not good code design. You can get strange errors down the road when changing folders, using includes or changing operating systems. A better alternative is using constants with absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution:

```
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefromgif('../images/watermark.gif');

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

        $errors= array();

        foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){

            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
            $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  

            //if($file_size > 2097152){

                //$errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
            //}
            // echo '<img src="../images/watermark.gif">';

            $q = "INSERT INTO media (file_name, album_id, file_size) VALUES ('$file_name','$album_id', '$file_size')";

            $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

            $desired_dir = '../../customers/' . $customerFolder . '/';

            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tmp);

            imagecopymerge($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp), 50);

            $newPath = "$desired_dir".$file_name;

            imagepng($im, $newPath);

            if(empty($errors)==true){

                    move_uploaded_file($newPath,"$desired_dir".$file_name);
                    imagedestroy($im);
                //mysql_query($q);  

            }else{
                print_r($errors);
            }
        }

        if(empty($error)){
            return 'ok';

        }else {
            return 'Kunne ikke uploade!';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `move_uploaded_file` with a `resource` variable.

move_uploaded_file accepts a string that is a absolute path to the temporary file.

since you already read the temporary file into a resource, you can just write the resource to the disk:

```
imagejpeg($photo,$desired_dir.$file_name);
```

temporary files are cleaned up automatically.